# Insert XML Data Into SQL Table with Foreign Keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have this XML File (there is data, but I deleted it for a purpose):

```
<NIACList>
<NIAC>
        <Number></Number>
        <SubmissionDate></SubmissionDate>
        <ExpirationDate  />
        <IssuerIDNO></IssuerIDNO>
        <IssuerName></IssuerName>
        <SuspensionPeriod/>
        <Cessation>
          <Basis  />
          <Date  />
        </Cessation>
        <Merchant>
          <IDNx></IDNx>
          <Name></Name>
          <Address>
            <Region></Region>
            <Locality></Locality>
            <Street></Street>
            <House></House>
            <Block  />
            <Flat  />
            <Phone  />
            <Fax  />
            <Email  />
          </Address>
        </Merchant>
        <CommercialUnit>
          <IDNx  />
          <Name  />
          <Type></Type>
          <Area></Area>
          <Location></Location>
          <Address>
            <Region></Region>
            <Locality></Locality>
            <Street></Street>
            <House></House>
            <Block  />
            <Flat  />
          </Address>
          <Activities>
            <Activity>
              <Code></Code>
              <Name></Name>
            </Activity>
          </Activities>
          <Goods>
            <Good>
              <Name></Name>
            </Good>
          </Goods>
          <WorkProgram  />
          <PublicSupplyUnit>
            <Capacity  />
            <TerraceCapacity  />
          </PublicSupplyUnit>
          <TradingAlcohol  />
          <TradingBeer  />
          <TradingTobaccoProducts  />
          <AmbulatoryTrading  />
          <MobileUnitTrading></MobileUnitTrading>
          <MobileUnit>
            <Type  />
            <Length  />
            <Width  />
            <Height  />
          </MobileUnit>
          <CommercialApparatusTrading></CommercialApparatusTrading>
          <CommercialApparatus>
            <Count  />
            <Length  />
            <Width  />
            <Height  />
          </CommercialApparatus>
        </CommercialUnit>
        <Modifications  />
      </NIAC>
</NIACList>
```

My task is to insert all XML data from this file into SQL Tables (SQL Server). I've inserted in most of the tables data, but here it is a problem. I have tables `Address` and `Merchant`. The first table doesn't have a foreign key, but the second table contains one, named `IdAddress`, so they could be relational. Is it possible to insert data into `Merchant`, so for each record from table `Address` will be linked with the `IdAddress` from `Merchant`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert the XML data in a buffer table - for example #temporary table. Then, first get the unique values that can be referred by the foreign key. Insert the one that do not exists. After that, join the #temporary table with the referenced table by the value and insert the value ID rather then the value.

Comment: which type of join between tables should I use for this situation?

Comment: @danmorcov `INNER JOIN` for the last `INSERT`. To insert values that does not exist in the first table, you can use `EXISTS`, `EXCEPT` or `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: So as I understand,the steps are:1)declare xml. 2)creating temp table Merchant. 3)set xml. 4)selecting the rows i want to insert data into temp table Merchant(IDNX,Name,WorkProgram,IdAddress).5)Joining temp table and table Address, which has the IdAddress already inserted I want to link.
Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, when you go the `Merchant` table - there you will have `address`, not the `id` of the address. So, get all addresses and insert the new one in the `address` table. Once they have `IDs` join the `Merchand` table t the `adress` table using `address` name and from there you will have the id.